# Android App asking for Google Mobile services on Huawei phones

Tags: android, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I am working on an android app that requires location and maps to be implemented in. for mobiles with Google support I was able to use the google play services and everything is working as supposed to.

Now come the problem with Huawei devices with no GMS support. I am using HMS as described and the app starts. but after a while a message saying that this app requires Google services to run and the app stops responding (app running in the background but no buttons can be pressed even if I force kill the app and restart it.

I started using the "Check API Availability" function in GMS it returned false and that is how I go to HMS.

So I tried another approach by creating a separate app for the Huawei devices and remove any GMS requirements. Yet again I am also getting that the app requires GMS.

I am attaching my build.gradle and manifest:

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'  // HUAWEI agconnect Gradle plugin


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "******"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++14"
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('***.jks')
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
            storePassword '***'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = [
                    "src/main/cppLibs/Poco/lib"
            ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.0'

    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.0.1.300'
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.3.301'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.yinglan.shadowimageview:shadowimageview:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.6.0'
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.+'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

}
```

and my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="***">



    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.appmarket.service.commondata.permission.GET_COMMON_DATA" />


    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

       .
       .
       .
       Bunch of Activities
       .
       .
       .
        <service
            android:name="*****"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

       
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Service.RebootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I even used Huawei HMS toolkit plugin to convert and it told me there is no GMS. where is that message coming from and why it is blocking my UI.

---EDIT----

Added the Project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files




classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.3.1.300'
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

-----EDIT 2------
Following m0skit0 advice i did dependency check and this is the result

```
.
.
.

lintClassPath - The lint embedded classpath
\--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.5.3
     +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.3
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.17
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50
     |    |    |    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50
     |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50
     |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50
     |    |    |    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.3
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:dvlib:26.5.3
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:repository:26.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12-b140109.1041
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.2.11
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:2.21
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.7.7
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.13
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6
     |    |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6
     |    |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10
     |    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     |    |    |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
     |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.5.3
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.5.3
     |    |         +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |         \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.3
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56
     |    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824
     |    \--- com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.4.0
     |         \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    |    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.2
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:23.0 -> 27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.5.3
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0
     |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0 (*)
     |    +--- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0
     |    +--- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9
     |    \--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.5.3
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824
     +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.3
     +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.5.3
     +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.3 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.5.3
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:6.0
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50 (*)
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.5.3
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:26.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50 (*)
.
.
.
.
```

I can see many google dependencies but non mentioned as google play (mainly in the QR generation library.) might those be the reason? is anything related to google not working on huawei?

Comment: Perhaps one of your dependencies are using GMS.

Comment: One of your dependencies uses GMS. You can use `gradle -q dependencies` you can see the dependency tree of your dependencies and see which one uses GMS.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you guide me how to do that in android studio please

Comment: Open console or terminal view and run `gradlew -q dependencies`.

Comment: @m0skit0 did your suggestion. nothing implicitly required play-services but there are many google requirements. (protobuf, guava..) might those be the reason?

Comment: You only listed the dependencies for com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.5.3. I suggest you output the result to a file so you can browse it more easily, for example `gradlew -q dependencies > dependencies.txt`. The resulting file should be in your project root directory.

Comment: @m0skit0 yeah but the file is to big to show here so I have shown the majority of "google" results which happened in the lint. BTW the command gradlew -q dependencies > dependencies.txt yielded an empty text i used ./gradlew -q app:dependencies > out.txt and that is how i got the above result

Comment: Look closer, I'm sure one of the dependencies has a dependency on GMS.

Comment: Btw, there's a quick win if you wish to support GMS&HMS location & maps in the same source code. Consider these wrapper libraries: https://github.com/abusuioc/hms-gms-wrapper-location & https://github.com/franalma/MapsWrapper

Comment: I would also check that the already written app has no calls to any error message method in: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability

Answer (score 0):

When we performed a test using the Gradle dependencies that you provided, we were not asked for GMS.
We think that:

1. Our test did not call the libraries in your project for generating QR codes but these libraries may depend on GMS. You can use [HUAWEI Scan Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/scan-generate-barcode-0000001050995005) to generate QR codes. It does not depend on HMS or GMS and can run on any devices.
2. You may have other local dependencies in the libs folder, or some C++ SDKs depend on GMS. You can remove them and try again.